# ValueError: install DBtypes to use this function

Tags: python, google-bigquery, valueerror, modulenotfounderror

I'm using BigQuery for the first time.

```
client.list_rows(table, max_results = 5).to_dataframe();
```

Whenever I use to_dataframe() it raises this error:

> ValueError: Please install the 'db-dtypes' package to use this function.

I found [this](https://github.com/feast-dev/feast/issues/2537) similar problem (almost exactly the same), but I can't understand how to implement their proposed solution.

Comment: Have you installed `db-dtypes` as indicated?

Comment: I checked, and there are no db-types specific module that I can pip install. It should have been installed along with pandas.

Comment: [`db-dtypes`](https://pypi.org/project/db-dtypes/) on PyPI.

Comment: pip install db-dtypes doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was able to replicate your use case as shown below.
[image]

Easiest solution is to `pip install db-dtypes` as mentioned by @MattDMo.

Or you can specify previous version of `google-cloud-bigquery` by creating a `requirements.txt` with below contents:

```
google-cloud-bigquery==2.34.3
```

And then pip install by using command as shown below:

```
pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt
```

Output of my sample replication:
[image]

Comment: Was able to make it work. Now I can get back to learning it bigquery. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried to install `pip install db-dtypes` but doesn't work.... Can anybody help?

Comment: @BrianIvanderT.P. Hey ! Have you solved it ?

Comment: @PeterMalik yeah I stop Jupyter Notebook then run it again hehe

Comment: yep, I needed to restart the kernel after the pip install

Answer (score 16):

The most robust way to resolve this is to specify that you also want to install [the `pandas` extra dependencies](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/1de7a52cb85d4876e4aa87346aff5725c8294c4e/setup.py#L54) when installing the `google-cloud-bigquery` package. You'd do this by

- running `pip install 'google-cloud-bigquery[pandas]'`, or
- putting e.g. `google-cloud-bigquery[pandas]==2.34.3` in your `requirements.txt`.