# pandas-gbq requires db-dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, google-bigquery

I can run my code from the terminal. But when I run it using the vscode debugger I get this error

> Exception has occurred: ImportError
> pandas-gbq requires db-dtypes

The error is in this line

```
df = pd.read_gbq(query, project_id='anyproject')
```

Comment: Have you tried installing db-dtypes ? "pip install db-dtypes"

Comment: Related answer for google-cloud-bigquery rather than pandas-gbq: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72511979/valueerror-install-dbtypes-to-use-this-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

This module `db-dtypes` will be automatically installed when installing `pandas-gbq`. It seems that your installation failed and you did not get it. You can try to install it separately by the following command:

```
pip install db-dtypes
```

or reinstall the `pandas-gbq`:

```
pip uninstall pandas_gbq
```

then

```
pip install pandas_gbq
```